# yii2 unknown property exception in GridView widget

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Yii2 : I have created a view of a table in mysql and created a raw query from this in model butt it is not accessible in view but it is perfect in phpmyadmin it is giving error unknown property how can we use it

**Query:**

```
SELECT `activated_promo`.*,rides_promo_count_view.count 
FROM `activated_promo` 
LEFT JOIN `promo_code` `promo` ON `activated_promo`.`promo_id` = `promo`.`id`
 LEFT JOIN `users` `customer` ON `activated_promo`.`userID` = `customer`.`ID`
 LEFT JOIN rides_promo_count_view on promo.id = rides_promo_count_view.promo_id
```

**View:**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            [
              'header'=>'No of Use',
              'value'=>function($data){
                 return empty($data->counte)?'':$data->counte;
                },
            ],
]); ?>
```

it's giving error unknown property

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the error

Comment: Also, your first column doesn't have the attribute specified. Which must be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SqlDataProvider, it'll give you arrays, not objects.

```
'value'=>function($data){
    return isset($data['counte']) ? '' : $data['counte'];
},
```